# Linq to Entities, Master Detail into DataContracts Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, datacontract

This is part of my WebAPI, and I'm having trouble getting this data out of Linq to entities into my Datacontract objects. I will be returning a custom data type to the caller, whether they want it XML or JSON, I don't care, I'm just handing this to WebAPI to take care of it.

I'm using VS2013 and EF5, ASP.NET 4.5 in C#

The structure is as follows:

**ProductCategory**

```
ID
CategoryName
(a million other things)
List<Products>
```

---

**Products**

```
ID
ProductName
(a million other things)
Category
```

---

I have set up a DataContract that looks like the following:

**ProductCategoryDataContract**

```
ProductCategoryId
ProductCategoryName
List<ProductDataContract> Products
```

---

**ProductDataContract**

```
ProductName
```

---

Basically, I want to get a Linq query to return ALL categories, and within it ALL products.

```
from prodcat in context.ProductCategories order by prodcat.ItemOrder
select new ProductCategoryDataContract
{
ProductCategoryId = prodcat.Id
Products = prodcat.Products // this obviously fails as ProductDataContract != Products
}
```

If I try

```
Products = new List<ProductDataContract> { //initializer stuff }
```

I don't have any of the intellisense things I would think I would have (ProductName, etc), because I'm guessing I'm in the list.

Basically, I have all the relationships set up and I can get everything in straight up EF, but because I'm putting these into new datacontracts, it's giving me a little grief (mostly due to my lack of linq knowledge).

My question is:
1.) how can I do this

and 
2.) how can I do this with minimal database hits. Potentially I'm firing off thousands of items within tens of product groups.

Thanks much, and if I'm not clear on anything, please lmk. And, the above is pseudocodish, not the real deal so if I made stupid naming errors, that's unlikely 'it' :)

Comment: Have you looked at automapper to map your Product to ProductDataContract? If many of your names and structures are the same, this is trivial

Comment: Sean, thanks.. I have not looked into automapper. The names and structures are mostly the same, there is some business logic I will add (such as URL to product image, which i have to do constant.path + product.imageUrl and such other nonsense). Automapper is a plugin, right? I'd like to avoid that if at all possible, especially if there is something "easy" i'm missing here (where I can initialize my 'master' with no problem, but not children... seems I'm missing something syntactically, but I'm new to this)

Comment: Who maintains this db? Because 1,000,003 columns looks a bit much ;)

Comment: Hahhahha, I maintain it, because I'm just as bad at SQL as I am EF. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IProducts
{
    int ProductId { get; set; }
    decimal Price { get; set; }
    List<IProductCategories> Categorieses { get; set; }
}

public interface IProductCategories
{
    int ProductId { get; set; }
    string ProductCategoryName { get; set; }
}

internal class Products : IProducts
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<IProductCategories> Categorieses { get; set; }
}

internal class ProductCategories : IProductCategories
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategoryName { get; set; }

    public ProductCategories(int productId, string productCategoryName)
    {
        ProductId = productId;
        ProductCategoryName = productCategoryName;
    }
}

public class ProductDataContract
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public List<IProductCategories> Categorieses { get; set; }
}
```

//Here is how you get your data:

```
        // your retun objects
        var products = new List<ProductDataContract>();

        using (
            var db =
                new DataClassesDataContext(
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {

            foreach (var prod in db.Products.Select(p => new Products {ProductId = p.ProductId}))
            {
                prod.Categorieses = new List<IProductCategories>();

                foreach (var category in db.ProductCategories.Where(c => c.ProductId == prod.ProductId))
                {
                    prod.Categorieses.Add(new ProductCategories(category.ProductId, category.ProductCategoryName));
                }

                products.Add(new ProductDataContract {Categorieses = prod.Categorieses, ProductId = prod.ProductId});
            }
        }
```

Comment: Alex, if you can help me a step further in this, how does all of this end up relating back to my EF objects, and how would that querying work? Thanks much for the response, it *seems* there should be something simple here since I can do the 'parent' with a contract so easily, I'd think that there's a way to effectively do the same thing with a subquery, but not really being a master at the linq/ef.... 
Thanks!

Comment: Alex, yes, if you could. I'm still struggling with the transformation from the entities to the datacontract for products (where I have things in Products like PurchasePrice, which cannot be exposed to the world what the seller paid for it). Thanks much, really appreciated

Comment: Hey Alex, I haven't tried setting up any of this yet, but aren't we going to have the same problem getting the EF datatype c.Products into ProductCategoryDataContract.Products? There's no transform there, it looks like they would end up being different types.

Comment: ooh! I like where this is going! I will give this a shot tonight